# HOW TO ADD a specific tables from all the tables in MYSQl

Tags: mysql, database

GUYS i just want a query of mysql . I have a database inside there are 3 tables . Each tables is having the same column names.

```
Table A:


CITY  
 A    
 G    
 Y     


TABLE B:

CITY 
 F    
 G   
 I    


TABLE C:

CITY 
 B 
 N   
 M
```

you can check above three tables column names are same
so i just want another table where only one column must be present using this data.
need this kind of table

```
CITY
A
G
Y
F
G
I
B
N
M
```

This table is nothing but collection of above tables PLs if anyone knows Query using mysql then pls pls pls reply

Thank you in advance

Comment: This schema appears to violate the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design).  Why don't you have all the cities in a single table, with an additional column to differentiate whatever distinguishes your existing tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `union` them.

```
SELECT city FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT city FROM TableB
UNION ALL
SELECT city FROM TableC
```

`union all` just combines the data of all tables. `union` (without `all`) filters duplicates and therefor is a bit slower, so don't use it unless you need to.

I do wonder though, why you have three different tables of cities in the first place. Why not have one?